# Why web3 utils BN not work correct with math?

Tags: javascript, web3js

I am trying do this:

```
import { BN } from 'web3-utils'

const AmountBN = new BN('1000000000000000000')
const res = AmountBN.mul(99).div(100)
console.log(res)
```

And get this

> Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Invalid array length at BN.mul (bn.js:1862)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is somewhat inflexible, but `mul()` and `div()` also expect BN as parameters, not numbers. And the result is a `BN` again, use `toString()`

So you need to write something like this:

```
const res = AmountBN.mul(new BN('99')).div(new BN('100'))
console.log(res.toString())
```

Comment: you can use `muln` and `divn` to use numbers :)